# Selecting text from a file removing unwanted text using shell

Tags: awk, sed

```
 [Time: 2017/04/03 07:27:30.048] [comp_ctrl]: Connecting to server......
    [Time: 2017/04/03 07:27:30.739] [comp_ctrl]: Connected to server.
    [Time: 2017/04/03 07:27:30.739] [comp_ctrl]: Execute list collabrations operation......
    The collaboration name:                                        The status:
    BooleanExpression1234                                          ACTIVE
    BooleanExpression1235`                                         INACTIVE
    There are total 2 collabrations listed.
```

For the above input,I want a shell program to output like below removing all other characters(finally output i require is to get the first column values which are only in INACTIVE status in second column)
File used to input will have multiple records.

```
BooleanExpression1234                                          ACTIVE
BooleanExpression1235                                          INACTIVE
```

I tried to get remove the unwanted contents through awk but not really working.

Comment: What did you try with awk? How did it fail? If you only want the INACTIVE lines, why are you showing ACTIVE in your output? Are you just looking for `grep INACTIVE file`? Please [edit] your question and clarify. And also mention your operating system.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$2 == "INACTIVE"{print $1}' input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting both ACTIVE and INACTIVE lines in the output:

grep ACTIVE sample.txt|awk -F " " '{print $1}'

---

For getting only INACTIVE line in the output:

grep INACTIVE sample.txt|awk -F " " '{print $1}'

Where sample.txt is the file containing the input text.

Comment: Glad to know :)